# PSQL Constraint based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to have a Constraint but only when one column is set to a particular value. For example take this pseudo-code example of a President which checks to make sure there is never more than 1 President at any time (note, this is **NOT** valid psql syntax)

```
CREATE TABLE president (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    current BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT there_can_be_only_one CHECK(COUNT(current=true)<=1)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the so called [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) to enforce this specific constraint. In SQL Server they are called filtered indexes.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX ON president (current)
WHERE current = true;
```

This index should prevent having more than one row in a table with `current` value set to `true`, because it is defined as unique.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **NO** as far as I know and anyway it already tells us,

`ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in check constraints`.

But we can use BEFORE trigger to check that the data you are trying to insert should meets the criteria `COUNT(current=true)<=1`

```
CREATE TABLE president (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    current BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION check_current_flag() 
RETURNS trigger 
AS $current_president$
DECLARE
  current_flag_count integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE current = true )
    INTO current_flag_count 
    FROM president;
 
 IF    new.current = true
   and current_flag_count >= 1 THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'There can be only one current president';
   -- RETURN NULL;
 ELSE
  RETURN NEW;
 END IF;
END;
$current_president$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER current_president BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON president
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_current_flag();
```

[Db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=118523c3c4d7b32e58edda762d7d51d4) for reference

**Note:**
You can either throw exception in case of preconditions doesn't match ore simply returning `NULL` will skip the insert and do nothing. as official document says also [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER:%7E:text=Row%2Dlevel%20triggers%20fired%20BEFORE%20can%20return,DELETE%20triggers%20is%20to%20return%20OLD.)

Comment: I think that for this specific constraint we can do it without a trigger, but by using a partial index. See my answer for details. If constraint requires some more complicated logic, a trigger would be appropriate solution.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov, you are right (didn't think that way +1) but nothing bad also having multiple options in hand :) but one advantage using trigger here that we can avoid `exception` and just skip the insertion